# Committed before 500,java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed

Tags: struts2, apache-poi

I'm using struts2 to export an excel file. A smaller file works fine. I get the following error with a larger file. Why am I getting this error? Is the file's size too large?

```
2012-12-01 09:51:29.689::WARN:  Committed before 500 Unable to show problem report: java.lang.IllegalStateException: STREAM
2012-12-01 09:51:29.690::WARN:  /strutsDemo/process/excel: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:853)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.reset(Response.java:832)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.sendError(Response.java:220)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:801)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:519)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1041)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:354)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:627)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:141)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:269)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:430)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:687)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:492)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:199)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.HttpChannelEndPoint.run(HttpChannelEndPoint.java:270)
    at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:475)
2012-12-01 09:51:29.691::WARN:  /strutsDemo/file/export
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:853)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.reset(Response.java:832)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.sendError(Response.java:220)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:801)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:519)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1041)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:354)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:627)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:141)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:269)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:430)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:687)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:492)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:199)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.HttpChannelEndPoint.run(HttpChannelEndPoint.java:270)
    at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:475)
```

Here is my action configuration:

```
  <result name="success" type="stream">
    <param name="contentType">application/vnd.ms-excel</param>
    <param name="inputName">excelStream</param>
    <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;fileName="${fileName}"</param>
    <param name="bufferSize">2048</param>
  </result>
  <result name="invalid.token">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: not enough information,provide details what you doing how you trying to export file else hard to say, with first sight it seems that stream is getting closed prematurely.

Comment: How are you receiving the file? Can you show us the code of that action, it you are not using annotations can you show us the xml that defines the configuration for it too? One reason I could find for the issue is when the HttpServletResponse is commited twice as per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162977/google-app-engine-java-lang-illegalstateexception-committed-error the only situation it can think of is possibly with a custom result type.

Comment: Show us your action configuration.

Comment: <result name="success" type="stream">
             <param name="contentType">application/vnd.ms-excel</param>
             <param name="inputName">excelStream</param> 
             <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;fileName="${fileName}"</param>
             <param name="bufferSize">2048</param>
             </result>
            <result name="invalid.token">/error.jsp</result> 
        </action>

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code started writing the Excel file (back to the client), got partway through, and encountered some kind of an error. By that time it was too late to go back and give a 500 HTTP error response code. The details of the error are not included in your question. (Could be the client hung up, response was committed twice, exception thrown by the application code, etc) If you debug your application and break on any Exception being thrown, do you find anything?

You can also try a much larger buffer size to see what happens. (4k, 16k, more?) This tells the system to hold on to the stream longer before starting to render it back to the client. Thus your actual problem might bubble to the top.